# EVENTOS en MYSQL, no se ejecuta

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

Muy buenas amigos estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de crear un evento en MySql.

Hace unos dias compre un servidor y agregue toda la informacion de mis paginas en el incluyendo la base de datos con las tablas.

Quiero ejecutar un UPDATE cada 24 horas en una tabla determinada llamada:
NEWAHORROSH

que contiene los datos

```
CREATE TABLE NEWAHORROSH(
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
user_id int not null,
capital_real float(11,2) not null,
intereses float(11,2) not null,
capital_total float(11,2) as (capital_real + intereses)
);
```

El codigo de mi evento es:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT CalculoIntereses
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR 
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
DO 
BEGIN
    IF(newahorrosh.capital_real>1 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <500) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*3*1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real>5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <1000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*4*1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real>1001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <5000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*5*1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real>5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <15000) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*6*1/36000));
    ELSEIF (newahorrosh.capital_real>15001) THEN
        UPDATE newahorrosh SET intereses= intereses + ((capital_real*7*1/36000));
    END IF;

END |

DELIMITER ;
```

El evento se me crea perfectamente sin errores pero cuando llega la hora en la que debe actualizarse la informacion no se ejecuta.
Ya me fije que el Schedule de events estuviera encendido en mi phpmyadmin.

repito no me tira error a la hora de crear el evento pero cuando abro mi evento en mi phpmyadmin me muestra unas X de errores en mi codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho la ayuda porque tengo casi 2 semanas intentando solucionar esto.
Mil gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Debo mencionar que antes este evento solamente ejecutaba una sola formula SIN NINGUN IF NI ELSE IF y ya no se me ejecuta despues de agregar el Delimiter y el IF anidado.
Saludos!

Comment: No tienes cláusula `ELSE`, deberías tener una?

Comment: Otra cosa que veo es esta condición `newahorrosh.capital_real>5001 AND newahorrosh.capital_real <1000`, esto siempre dará `FALSE`. Los límites están mal, nunca evaluas cuando es 1000, 5000 o 15000, debes usar un `<=` o un `>=` según sea el caso.

Comment: Mauricio Contreras gracias por tu comentario amigo, he tomado las correcciones pero sigue mostrándome los mismos errores en mi Evento

Comment: Hola, revisando tu código, veo que no dejas espacio entre tu cláusula IF y el argumento que escribes entre paréntesis. Mi recomendación sería que obviases los paréntesis. No hacen falta, a menos que estés realizando un cálculo dentro de los mismos. Y si los vas a usar debes dejar un espacio entre `IF` y el primer paréntesis. Recuerda que en MySQL existe la función `IF()`. Tal vez allí tengas tu problema. Prueba lo que te sugiero y comentas.

Comment: Tienes algun punto y coma, probablemente hay radique el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newahorrosh.capital_real` está fuera de contexto. 
Sugiero la siguiente sintaxis:

```
BEGIN
   UPDATE newahorrosh 
     SET intereses = intereses 
                   + capital_real/36000
                   * CASE 
                       WHEN capital_real > 1 AND capital_real <= 500
                         THEN 3
                       WHEN capital_real > 500 AND capital_real <= 1000
                         THEN 4
                       WHEN capital_real > 1001 AND capital_real <= 5000
                         THEN 5
                       WHEN capital_real > 5001 AND capital_real <= 15000
                         THEN 6
                       WHEN capital_real > 15001
                         THEN 7
                     END;
END |
```

Con la reserva de que ajustes el manejo de rangos con `>=` y/o `<=` según tu regla de negocio.

Los paréntesis no los necesitas por que te ayuda la *precedencia de operadores*.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes puesto `;` al final de la sentencia `THEN` y comienzas la otra línea con `ELSEIF`.

o le quitas el `;` o cambias el `ELSEIF` por solo `IF`.